# What do the green underscores in the Script section of my cshtml indicate, and how can I ungreenify them?

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2013, resharper, resharper-2016

In Visual Studio (2013, if it's significant) I see this in the "Scripts" section of a .cshtml file:

[image]

The green undersscores may actually be being rendered by Resharper (version 2016.1, if it's significant).

I suspect this is some sort of warning, but how can I see what the warning is, and how to resolve whatever is causing the warning? Hovering does nothing; 2-clicking does invoke a "Format Selection" icon (doubtless from Resharper), but selecting it does nothing.

Comment: If I had to wager a guess, I would think that since Resharper sees that this is Javascript code, it might be expecting that the variables and properties would be camel-cased (i.e. `dayOfMonth` as opposed to `DayOfMonth`) and it could simply be a code-style preference that you might be able to disable. With regards to the `var` usage, it might recommend something like `let` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a ReSharper hint - it's saying that it can make a change here that is likely to improve your code, but isn't necessarily important (if it were more important it would be displayed as a full squiggly underline, green for suggestion, blue for warning, red for error).

You can find out what ReSharper wants to do by hovering over the green dots. If you like the hint, put the text cursor inside the green dots, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select the option that will update the code. If you don't like the hint at all, and never want to see it again, you can also do that from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> menu - select inspection options, and change the severity of the inspection from "Hint" to "Do not show".